# Can creatures in the Monster Manuals make melee basic attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, attack

Are creatures in the monster manuals (and other official sources) limited only to actions in their stat block, or can they use the options available to characters?

If they can, then the Melee Basic Attack actually ends up being much more damaging than the attacks that some creatures are described as having (such as Pit Fiends) as the attack would directly apply their strength modifier as damage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, creatures only have the attacks listed in the manual. You'll have to pick one of those.

They can't make Melee Basic Attacks, and you wouldn't be able to calculate what they did anyway because monsters don't follow the normal rules for weapons so you wouldn't know what to use for the damage roll, plus they don't have Feats and no magic weapons or other items needed to get a decent attack roll so you wouldn't be able to give them decent accuracy either.

That said; each monster does have some kind of power that it can use *as* a Melee Basic Attack in case a different game ability references it. (Opportunity attacks for example). The attack that the monster uses in place of a Melee Basic Attack is the one with a circle around the attack-type symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only as specified in their stat block. Usually, the Melee Basic Attack is located at the top of the listed attacks, symbolized with a circled sword. It is used mostly for reactions and the damage is specified in the block, not using any extra calculations.

Comment: While I think this is correct, this answer would be improved with a citation from the rules.